# Metis 5.1 gives Memory allocation failed for SetupCtrl: ctrl->tpwgts

Tags: fortran, partitioning, metis

I am trying to partition ~ 3 million mesh. My Fortran program calls following -

```
   METIS_PartGraphKway(gp%ncv_ib,ncon,nbocv_i,nbocv_v,0,0, &
    0,npart,tpwgts,ubvec,options,edgecut,part)

    `ncon = 1, npart = 10
    allocate(ubvec(ncon))
    ubvec(:) = 1.01
    allocate(tpwgts(ncon*npart))
    tpwgts(:) = 1.0/REAL(npart)
    options(:)= 0`
```

Earlier I was using Metis that comes with Parmet 3.0 and it was working fine. Now if I use metis 5.1, it gives me following error -

`Current memory used: 392 bytes Maximum memory used: 392 bytes ***Memory allocation failed for SetupCtrl: ctrl->tpwgts. Requested size: 10842907309714178088 bytes` 
I am specifying `IDXTYPEWIDTH 64 and REALTYPEWIDTH 64`

Comment: Try using the technique described here to solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  If you get it down to a minimal solution that reproduces your problem, you may even find it easier to debug yourself. Good luck.

Comment: It looks like the function call may have changed. Check the documentation and make sure you're using the correct arguments.

Comment: I  have already changed the function call according to metis 5.1, but no success - `int METIS PartGraphKway(idx t *nvtxs, idx t *ncon, idx t *xadj, idx t *adjncy, idx t *vwgt, idx t *vsize, idx t *adjwgt, idx t *nparts, real t *tpwgts, real t ubvec, idx t *options, idx t *objval, idx t *part)`

Comment: Sorry for necrobumping. I got this error when the the `nparts` parameter was -1.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem? I met this problem also.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I passed parameter `nvtxs = n+1` instead of `n`, where `n` is number of vertices in a graph.